# Python vectorize 2d and 3d array concatenation with different dimensions

Tags: python, matrix, concatenation, vectorization

I am trying to implement message passing in graph neural nets. In each graph, there are edges and nodes and a node-to-edge update is implemented as follows:
[image: node-to-edge update] Where the square brackets denote the concatenation operation, subscripts are indexes and the superscripts are time indexes.

So I am trying to concatenate 3 matrixes of dimensions: AxN, AxBxM, and BxN. And the resulting concatenation is of dimension: AxBx(2N+M). So every (i,j) of the resulting matrix is a concatenation of the ith row of the first matrix, jth row of the third matrix and the (i,j)th element of the second matrix. I managed to implement this in a double for loop as follows:

```
edge_in = torch.zeros(a, b, m +  2 * n)
        edge_in = edge_in.cuda()
        for i in range(a):
          for j in range(b):
              edge_in[i,j] = torch.cat((nodes_a_embeds[i], edge_embeds[i,j], nodes_b_embeds[j]))
```

However, this is excruciatingly slow. Is this in any way vectorizable? I tried to come up with a solution and then I looked for a solution online but couldn't manage to vectorize it. Thanks.

edit: numeratic example as requested:

First matrix: 5x3
Second matrix: 5x4x2
Third matrix: 4x3

Output should be 5x4x8 then. Let's call our output matrix R.

Then R(1,2) = concatenate(First(1),Second(1,2),Third(2)).

Comment: Can you add an example input of the three arrays and an example expected output?

Comment: Added an example, is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this be the correct implementation of your code?

```
import numpy as np

A = 2
B = 3
M = 4
N = 5

first = np.arange(A*N).reshape((A, N))
first = np.tile(first[:, np.newaxis, :], (1, B, 1))

second = np.arange(A*B*M).reshape((A, B, M))

third = np.arange(B*N).reshape((B, N))
third = np.tile(third[np.newaxis, :, :], (A, 1, 1))

result = np.concatenate((first, second, third), axis=2)
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  0,  1,  2,  3,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  4,  5,  6,  7,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  8,  9, 10, 11, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 12, 13, 14, 15,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 16, 17, 18, 19,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 20, 21, 22, 23, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]])
```